# How to organize controllers and views when I need first-load screen

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development and a bit lost. My question is both about general user experience and concrete architecture advices.

Basically my app should work as follows:

At first start it requests information from remote server, requests user location with GPS. While these things happening, app should display some kind of first-launch view with progress indicator and text. First question is: what if user can't download information from remote server? This information is essential and app can't continue to work without it. Should I just retry to download? Should I present some MessageBox to user? With desktop application I would present user two choices - Retry or Exit. Exit is not acceptable in iOS applications, so should I present message box? Or I just need to inform user about problems via text on this first-launch view and silently retry to download information until it succeeds? Or create button "Retry" and let user do that?

If device provided user location and download was successful, I have all information needed to continue. Otherwise user must choose his country and city before continue.

Then I have 3 tabs with different functionality. I already implemented that.

So my question is: how to display first-load view and it's controller? Should I check in appdelegate initialization method and assign first-load view as main view and then reassign to usual application UITabbarController (not sure how to do it)? Or I need to set UITabbarController as root controller and in first tab controller on initializing I should check if it is first-time start and call something like presentViewController for first-time view controller? I would like to implement this check somewhere else, appdelegate is good place for that, because initialization code doesn't really belong to first tab controller.

I created sample programs with multiple views which were managed by UITabbarController or UINavigationController, but I don't understand how to manage multiple views myself, without helper controllers which did that work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently developing an app with similar behavior.

I use a UINavigationController as the root controller. After that, I have a view controller with a UIActivityIndicatorView on it. I start the animation in the ViewWillAppear method and call the method that implements the remote call in the ViewDidAppear method.

If the call succeeds, I go to the next view.

If the call fails, I use an UIAlertView to notify the user and they tap OK to retry.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view controller to be displayed with `presentViewController:animated:completion:` while the data is being loaded and display it in the `viewDidLoad` of the root view controller.

I'd use something like [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) to do the loading from the server.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://your-url.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // Dismiss the loading view controller and proceed as normal
} failure:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ) {
    // Display an alertView that gives the option to retry
}];
[operation start];
```

Be sure to wrap any UI updates in the block in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` call make the update happen on the main thread.